# Why does this simple Python code raise UnboundLocalError and why changing a line affect the lines before it?

Tags: python

This is an embarrassingly simple code, but producing very weird result:

```py
import os

print(dir(os))

def main():
    print(dir(os))
    import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that there are 2 `print(dir(os))` on lines 3 and 6. Very weirdly:

1. Line 3 runs just fine and line 6 throws `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'os' referenced before assignment`.
2. If I remove/comment out line 7 (`import os` again), the code runs just fine.

My Question:

1. Why does the original code throw `UnboundLocalError`?
2. Why does changing line 7 affect line 6? My understanding is that the Python interpreter runs sequentially and code never affect what comes before it.

Additional information:

1. Replacing `os` with other modules gets the same result (e.g. `numpy`).
2. Reproduced with Python 3.6 - 3.9.
3. My best guess is since `main` is a function, the interpreter will scan the function first and record all symbols. In this case, in the initial scan, it marks a local variable `os` in the function, and in the second run, the *local variable* `os` is referenced before assignment, and hence the error. Because replacing line 7 with `import os.path` also gives the same error, but replace with "import os.path as osp` works fine again.

Comment: `import` is an assignment (please see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html); the rest is explained by the usual logic (as per the linked duplicate).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` is an assignment statement. When a variable is assigned in a function, and you haven't declared it global, it's a local variable, so the global variable is not used. But you try to use `os` *before* you assign it with the `import` statement.

It's the same reason you'll get that error if you do:

```
myvar = 3

def main():
    print(myvar)
    myvar = 4

main()
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar, for the quick response! Could you elaborate a bit more on the why part? I mean why does the interpreter behave this way such that change of a line affects what's before it. For example, in my additional information bullet point 3, I had a conjecture. Does that look correct?

Comment: @seekiu yes your conjecture #3 looks right to me.

Comment: That's how Python scope works. It looks at the whole function to decide if a variable is local or global. @seekiu